# Elasticsearch 5.6 returns very slow response with Laravel 5.8 when Wifi is connected in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-5

I am facing a strange problem while using Elasticsearch 5.6 with Laravel 5.8 when Wifi/Wired Internet is connected. Even when a new index is created in a fresh Elasticsearch installation, the same problem persists. Sometimes the response is so slow that it takes 2-3 minutes to create a new index in a fresh elastic search installation. A similar issue is there for running even a basic search query. However, the REST queries run through the browser/CLI do not have any issues.

When Wifi/Wired Internet is not connected, it returns a very quick response. It looks to be some issue with PHP or Guzzle package used in the background. But I am not sure. I use the Elasticsearch PHP library in Laravel.

For example to create an index:

```
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()// Instantiate a new ClientBuilder
                    ->setHosts($config)      // Set the hosts
                    ->setRetries(2)
                    ->build();
```

**System configuration:**

1. Ubuntu 18.04
2. PHP 7.2
3. Laravel 5.8.38
4. Elasticsearch 5.6.0

Can anyone please explain what could be the issue and how I can get rid of this?

Thanks.

Comment: Whats your kernel version on the server?

Comment: You should use some sort of network monitoring tool e.g. like wireshark to see what's going on in your network when connected. This isn't a problem with ES itself (as you yourself can confirm when you run the same thing without an internet connection)

Comment: What is your system configurations where elasticsearch is running ?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is facing the same problem can try passing `['host:port']` as string in `$client->setHosts()` instead of passing array to it `['host'=>'localhost', 'port'=>9200]`.

For example:

```
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
                    ->setHosts(['localhost:9200'])
                    ->setRetries(2)
                    ->build();
```

This solved my problem !